# Cassandra copying few keyspace from a single node to another existing single node

Tags: java, nosql, cassandra

I am having single node cassandra (Cassandra A) where there are 10 keyspace. And there is also another single node cassandra (Cassandra B) where there are 20 keyspace. I want to move or copy 5 keyspace from Cassandra A to Cassandra B.

I tried by copying the data directory of those 5 keyspace into Cassandra B data directory. And i started the cassandra B but those 5 keyspace are not available.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: And the question is... ?

Comment: @Eel Lee: I need to copy 5 keyspace to another existing node?? How to achieve it??

Comment: Did you ever find a neat solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just copy data directories, because Cassandra maintains some metadata information about its keyspaces in its system tables.

Have you tried using the bulkloader ? (http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/webhelp/index.html#cassandra/tools/toolsBulkloader_t.html)

Comment: By using BulkLoader we have to create keyspace and column family in the destination node manually then we have to do bulk loader process. I can't do that manually since my real requirement is to copy more than 100 keyspace which contains totally more than 500 column family totaly. So this will not be a good solution for my case. I want to map all 5 keyspace along with its column family to the destination node automatically..